# GMP limitation big integer

Tags: biginteger, gmp, digit

i have a problem with GMP library for big integer.
I set the big integer using the function

mpz_t num;

mpz_init(num);

**mpz_set_str(num,"123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012341234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123412345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456",10);**

When i print this number gmp_printf("%Zd",num) the result is wrong.
Are there any limitations? Is the number too big? i don't think ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mpf_set_default_prec(5*1024);
```

before your mpz_init.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you didn't initialize num. The GMP functions for integer arithmetic assume that all integer objects are initialized.

```
mpz_init(num);
```

Comment: I correct my program ( mpz_init(num) ) but the result  is 122807895200671984128507422487887949487086983636899608718955860947262867625201744395928018576439955322671223344601323257833532774452710739238096467020229350927138577087690181112358030675315727199589153472 .Very strange!

Comment: I tried with the same number and it works for me. Please paste all your code.

Comment: mpz_t num;

mpz_init(num);


mpz_set_str(num,"123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012341234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123412345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456",10);

gmp_printf("ecco il numero %Zd\n",num);

Comment: OK now I'm definitely stuck. Do you have the last version of GMP?

Comment: 5.0.1 . I work with Mac osx. Perhaps there is a sort of Hardware limitation. I don't know. It's very strange.

Comment: I am using macbook air with latest version GMP.